# Make GridBagLayout JPanel size to contents, not container?

Tags: java, swing, size, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a `GridBagLayout` `JPanel` contained within a `BorderLayout` `JPanel`.  I want the `GridBagLayout` to size itself to its internal grid.  Instead, it sizes itself to the `BorderLayout`, adding whitespace to the sides of the internal grid (all weights in the `GridBagLayout` are 0).

The idea is that I want the `BorderLayout` to supply the whitespace (with glue). Instead, the `GridBagLayout` is supplying the whitespace; you can see that by looking at the `TitleBorder` I added.

The reason for this is that when I send the `GridBagLayout` to my printer, I don't want all that whitespace included.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GBLDemo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Demo");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jframe.setContentPane(contentPane);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel gb = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.add(gb);

        gbc.gridx = gbc.gridy = 0;
        gb.add(new JLabel("Look "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("at"), gbc);         

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("the "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("border"), gbc);

        gb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Border"));

        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setSize(640, 480);
    } // main(args)
} // GBLDemo
```

Here's an ASCII mockup of what I want:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
|                                           |
|           +Border-----+                   |
|           |Look  at   |                   |
|           | the border|                   |
|           +-----------+                   |
|                                           |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Here's the display produced by the code above:

[image]

Comment: We can't possible guess what you are doing based on your verbal description of the problem. Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @camickr Done!  Is this better?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Will this do?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what is needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good trick for center a component at its preferred size (e.g. the `contentPane` in the code in the question) is to add it as a single component to a container with a grid bag layout, without specifying a constraint.

Here is the code from above, adapted to do exactly that.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GBLDemo {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    GBLDemo() {
        initUI();
    }

    private Container getContentPanel() {
        Container contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel gb = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.add(gb);

        gbc.gridx = gbc.gridy = 0;
        gb.add(new JLabel("Look "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("at"), gbc);         

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("the "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("border"), gbc);

        gb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Border"));
        return contentPane;
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        // A single object added to a grid bag layout with no constraint, 
        // will be centered within the available space.
        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        ui.add(getContentPanel());
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                GBLDemo o = new GBLDemo();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your suggestion (although not your code, which I need to analyze to understand the unrelated differences from my usual approach) and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution with an Absolute Layout (null) would be something like this:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GBLDemo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Demo");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        jframe.setContentPane(contentPane);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setSize(640, 480);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel gb = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.add(gb);

        gbc.gridx = gbc.gridy = 0;
        gb.add(new JLabel("Look "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("at"), gbc);         

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("the "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gb.add(new JLabel("border"), gbc);

        gb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Border"));
        gb.setSize(gb.getPreferredSize());
        gb.setLocation(jframe.getWidth()/2-gb.getWidth()/2, jframe.getHeight()/2-gb.getHeight()/2);

        jframe.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                gb.setSize(gb.getPreferredSize());
                gb.setLocation(jframe.getWidth()/2-gb.getWidth()/2, jframe.getHeight()/2-gb.getHeight()/2);
            }
        });        

    } // main(args)
} // GBLDemo
```

Producing this:
[image: code results]

gb JPanel will always be at the center, ComponentListener takes care of that. gp will change its size to fit automatically the contained objects with `gb.setSize(gb.getPreferredSize());` .

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but I want the size of the GridBagLayout to be calculated automatically, to fit tightly around the grid.  My goal is to get rid of that whitespace surrounding it.

Comment: @BruceFeist I modified the source code according to your comments. All you needed is gb.setSize(gb.getPreferredSize());

Comment: This looks like a good solution to me, although I went with @AndrewThompson 's.  I prefer avoiding AbsoluteLayout if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your panel, gb, directly to the contentPanel, you could add another panel with a GridBagLayout to the contentPane and add your panel, gb, to that panel (without fill).

The 'center' component of a Panel with a BorderLayout always gets all the remaining space, after the north/east/west/south components are given their preferred sizes.  So the middle-man component above will 'absorb' all the space given to it by the BorderLayout and, as long as you didn't add gb with a "fill" constraint, it should show up centered the way you wanted it.

Comment: This didn't make a difference for me.  Switching from BorderLayout to another GridBagLayout as @AndrewThompson suggested is almost the same, though, and that did work.